# C# String Build

Tags: c#, string

I'm sorry if similar question is already answered but I couldn't find answer to my problem.
My problem is that until now I used this code for representing article specifications:

```
var res = context.ArticleSpecification(articleId, (byte)Settings.LanguageId)
                .Select(e => string.Format("{0}: {1}", e.CRITERIA_DES_TEXT, e.CRITERIA_VALUE_TEXT));

            return string.Join("; ", res);
```

And I get results in one line divided by ; like this:

```
? Holes [mm]: 28.57; Thread Size: 10 x 1.25; Material: Cast iron; for product number: 4407; Mounting hole clearance [mm]: 36
```

Can anyone help me building multi line string, and every new line starts after e.CRITERIA_VALUE_TEXT and get results like this:

```
? Holes [mm]: 28.57
Thread Size: 10 x 1.25
Material: Cast iron
for product number: 4407
Mounting hole clearance [mm]: 36
```

Thank You in advance!!!

Comment: `\n` instead of `;`?

Comment: use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `;` in `string.Join()`